# Prevent user from creating multiple accounts with one e-mail address?

Tags: php, email, mysqli

Let's say a user is making an account on a website. The e-mail address which is provided by user is saved in mysql, but is hashed before saving. That way a possible hacker is not going to see the e-mail addresses. But on the other hand for me or you ("the programmer") there is no way to see if an user is trying to create an account with the same e-mail address (which I really want to prevent).

Question: In general what is your advice to cope with this problem? Any advice or solutions are appreciated?

Question: Would an account be more "secure" when hashing the e-mail address?

P.S. FYI, this application uses PHP as server language.

UPDATE:

1. I use BCRYPT with PHP built in salt.
2. I use mysqli.

Comment: Create a unique index on the email.  This will prevent multiple users from using the same address.

Comment: Surely you can hash the e-mail address of the second account, using the same hash function, and see if the resulting hashes are the same?

Comment: @S.L.Barth , That won't work (right now) the e-mail address is hashed with an salt provided by php and thus will change. So the hash won't be the same when hashed again. Would you suggest hashing without a salt? Have not thinked about that yet.

Comment: hash codes wont change when each time you generate it for same string so better check the hashcode (i.e) email id before saving it for unique constraint

Comment: Are you using bcrypt? Off the top of my head bcrypt stores the salt with the hash, so you can actually find it back. But assuming the salt is not based solely on the e-mail address, you would have to try all salts in the database - and password hashes are designed to be slow.

Comment: @GordonLinoff , unique index of the email? Please tell me how to do that or point me to an site?

Comment: @S.L.Barth Yes I am using Bcrypt! and that indeed would take a massive amount of time to check all of the rows. Any other ideas?

Comment: @user3892683 `ALTER TABLE foo ADD UNIQUE INDEX (email) USING BTREE;` To add a unique constraint to the email field. [Asked here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28832657/prevent-user-from-creating-multiple-accounts-with-one-e-mail-address#comment45935224_28832657)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solution #1 - MySQL approach

Add `unique` index on `email` column. This will prevent any additional rows with identical `email` field to be added. No error, smooth.

Assuming your table is `users` and you store emails in `email_hashed`:

```
ALTER TABLE users
ADD UNIQUE (email_hashed)
```

Needs cleaning first before applying if you already have duplicates.

.

## Solution #2 - PHP approach

Simply hash email and `SELECT` from database all rows with that hash. Like that:

```
$email = 'ex@example.com';
$hashed = someHashing($email);
$sql = ("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email_hashed = '$email'");
..
```

If any row will be fetched then you can do something like displaying message, error or anything.

---

I recommend using both solutions.

### EDIT - Regarding... BCrypt...

So yeah, you are using `BCrypt`. There are two ways for you if you want to hash emails (no idea why, but whatever!). The one for which you will gonna be laughed by everyone and the better one.

The first (laughable) one is to:

1. `SELECT` from database entire table with every possible existing hash of emails
2. Run `foreach() {}` loop through every hash from database
3. In every loop compare hashes using `password_verify()`
4. If any compare returns `true` then run some code of your own

The second one is easy:

- *CHANGE hashing to either `md5` (using `md5('text')` function) or `sha256` for longer hashes (using `hash('sha256','text')`)*

### Another edit

> Question: Would an account be more "secure" when hashing the e-mail address?

I think it's not question to raise on *StackOverflow* but since it's "a bonus" I will put some thoughts here.

I am not security expert though, so it's possible that I don't know something.

Anyway, hashing passwords with `BCrypt` and being sure that nothing on the account can be edited in **any** way that don't require passwords (like flawed API or compromised admin dashboard). I think you should also protect vulnerable data (like names, addresses, phone numbers etc) from public access.

Hashing emails has **only one** purpose I can think of. That in case of successfull hack, someone who dumped all your database won't get any single email address. That is nice. But it also prevents you from sending newsletters, account expiration notices and other important emails.

In 90% of sites I'd say "hashing emails, are you insane?", but if you don't need to reuse email at all (you won't ever send any email except registration one) and want user emails to be pretty safe, then yes, hashing can prove useful. But please, no `BCrypt` :P

Comment: You should add the query that will apply a unique constraint to the field.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ since I have no idea which database connetcion library is OP using, I didn't put any specific code. I don't want to put `mysqli` when he is using `PDO` or writing `PDO` when OP uses for example `adoDB`.

As for query to unique constraint. Why? He can do that through `PHPMyAdmin` or `Adminer` or any other way. No need to do that every time in queries when adding new user

Comment: Yes I am using mysqli .

Comment: @Forien The question is tagged `mysql`, so a simple MySQL query would suffice. You raise a valid point regarding doing it through PMA or Adminer, but people in the future who have a similar issue and don't have these tools will need to do further research rather than get a whole complete (I use the term "complete" loosely, I've +1 this answer) answer in one place.

Comment: @Forien Ok, thanks for the answer, but AFAIK both won't work. I use BCRYPT (which is using an salt) and when using the same password the hashed version will vary each time. So you can't create a unique index because it will change next time because of the salt. And the second won't work either because of the salt. Am I right here? Should I make a change to the hashing algorithm?

Comment: why are you so heavy on the hashing? You seem to be causing yourself more work by making everything not even one way readable. If you are using built in salts with BCRYPT then the salt is built into the hash and so you would need to run through and check each row in your database, but it would at least be possible, if tediously slow. Using your own salts is really not advised

Comment: @user3892683 Well, I have **no idea at all** why you are using `BCrypt` for emails. It's for passwords to compare two hashes if they came from the same source. If you insist on hashing emails, use `md5()` or `hash('sha256')`, becuase otherwise you need to select **entire** users table and run `foreach` loop to compare **every** hash with `password_verify()` which would suck.

Comment: @Forien Good point! I am fairly new to hashing and such and founded and used Bcrypt. but  you are totally right about md5 and sha256. Will use that instead!

Comment: @user3892683 glad I could help. I've also scribed some edit regarding the other question

Answer (score 1):

As S.L Barth states, you can hash the email address as given, perhaps with an ajax request once the field looses focus, and then check if that hash exists in the database, if number of rows returned is > 0 then javascript can output a message saying this account is already registered.

Creating a unique index on the table would also work but this would not feedback an issue until the data was attempted to be written to the database, which will probably be too late. Needless looping for the end user.

### Update

If your email address is hashed with a salt and you can't confirm it against the same email address added again, what is the point of storing the email address if it can not be decrypted? Revise your method. Use a php function like `Password_hash()` and `password_verify()`

Comment: It is also *NOT* recommended to use your own salts when saving hashes.

Comment: thanks I use BCRYPT with the built in hashing so that would not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you hash the email to insert it into the database check if such hashed email already exists, just like you check for that each time a user is logging in.

Accounts would be more secure if you hash everything but that way it would be hard to recover/reset lost username/password because you wouldn't know to what email to send the reset information

Answer (score -1):

on onblur event hashed the email id entered by user and check it whether it is present in mysql email column if it is present it will result in a row then disable button else allow user to insert

use select * from user where email="hashed(email_id_entered)"

if(result>0)
disable button
else
enable